# Zoom in background when container height increases

Tags: android, bitmap, zooming

I have a relative layout that expands/collapses when a user taps on it. This container has a background that I want to zoom in when the view expands and zoom out(to the initial zoom) when the container collapses.

Could anyone please give me an ideea on how I can accomplish this effect.

Thanks!

Comment: What you tried? Show use some code, at least layout code.

Comment: It's just a simple relative layout that changes it;s height when a user taps on it.